# Distintos ProgressDialog en request recursivo usando Volley y AsyncTask

Tags: android

Hola estoy haciendo un `request` usando la librería `Volley` a un `API` para obtener muchos registros aproximadamente 8.000 y guardarlos en una `BD`.

El `response` del `API` trae un parámetro `count` con el total de los objetos y el parámetro `next` con la siguiente url, por cada request retorna `500 objetos`.

Durante el `JsonObjectRequest` utilizo un `ProgressDialog` con estilo `Spinner`, si el request trae objetos en el `onResponse` del `JsonObjectRequest` realizo el parse del response en un `AsyncTask`.

Cuando ejecuto el `AsyncTask` para realizar el parser y guardar la información en la `BD` utilizo un ProgressDialog de estilo Horizontal indicando el porcentaje de la tarea.

El problema es el `ProgressDialog` durante el request a la API este se ejecuta solo la primera vez y desde la segunda me da el siguiente error:

```
01-28 18:11:52.824 13527-13572/? W/System.err: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
01-28 18:11:52.824 13527-13572/? W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:200)
01-28 18:11:52.824 13527-13572/? W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:114)
01-28 18:11:52.824 13527-13572/? W/System.err:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewRootHandler.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:3108)
01-28 18:11:52.824 13527-13572/? W/System.err:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:3393)
01-28 18:11:52.824 13527-13572/? W/System.err:     at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:271)
01-28 18:11:52.824 13527-13572/? W/System.err:     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:85)
01-28 18:11:52.824 13527-13572/? W/System.err:     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:298)
01-28 18:11:52.824 13527-13572/? W/System.err:     at com.dominio.sti.api.SincronizarPredios.sincronizar(SincronizarPredios.java:62)
01-28 18:11:52.825 13527-13572/? W/System.err:     at com.dominio.sti.api.SincronizarPredios$ParserPredio.doInBackground(SincronizarPredios.java:167)
01-28 18:11:52.825 13527-13572/? W/System.err:     at com.dominio.sti.api.SincronizarPredios$ParserPredio.doInBackground(SincronizarPredios.java:96)
01-28 18:11:52.825 13527-13572/? W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:292)
01-28 18:11:52.825 13527-13572/? W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
01-28 18:11:52.825 13527-13572/? W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
01-28 18:11:52.825 13527-13572/? W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
01-28 18:11:52.825 13527-13572/? W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
01-28 18:11:52.825 13527-13572/? W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Este es el código:

```
public class SincronizarPredios {

    final String url = Constants.getApiUrl();
    final Date fecha = new Date();
    final PredioSQL predioSQL;
    final SincronizacionSQL sincronizacionSQL;
    final Context context;
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    UserLocalStore userLocalStore;
    String token;

    public SincronizarPredios(Context appContext) {
        context = appContext;
        predioSQL = new PredioSQL(context);
        sincronizacionSQL = new SincronizacionSQL(context);
        userLocalStore = new UserLocalStore(context);

        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
        progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        progressDialog.setTitle("Conectando con el servidor...");
        progressDialog.setMessage("Obteniendo predios...");
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
    }

    public void sincronizar(String nextUrl, Integer zona_id) {

        String fullUrl = url + "predios/?zona=" + zona_id;

        token = userLocalStore.getApiKey();

        if (nextUrl != null) {
            fullUrl = nextUrl;
        }

        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, fullUrl,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject jsonResponse) {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        new ParserPredio().execute(jsonResponse);
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                }) {
            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                params.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
                params.put("Accept", "application/json");
                params.put("Authorization", "Token " + token);
                return params;
            }

        };

        VolleySingleton.getInstance(context).addToRequestQueue(jsonObjectRequest);
        progressDialog.show();
    }

    public class ParserPredio extends AsyncTask<JSONObject, Integer, Boolean> {
        private Integer porcAvance;
        private Float division;

        ProgressDialog pDialog;

        public ParserPredio() {
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
            pDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
            pDialog.setMessage("Guardando predios...");
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.setMax(100);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {

            pDialog.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
                    ParserPredio.this.cancel(true);
                }
            });

            pDialog.setProgress(0);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(JSONObject... params) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonResponse = params[0];
                Integer count = jsonResponse.getInt("count");
                if (count > 0) {
                    JSONArray resultados = jsonResponse.getJSONArray("results");
                    String next = jsonResponse.getString("next");
                    division = (float) 100 / resultados.length();
                    for (int i = 0; i < resultados.length(); i++) {
                        if(isCancelled()){
                            break;
                        }
                        JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) resultados.get(i);
                        Integer id_remota = jsonObject.getInt("id");
                        String nombre = jsonObject.getString("nombre");
                        String codigo_siscop = jsonObject.getString("codigo_siscop");
                        String codigo_sap = jsonObject.getString("codigo_sap");
                        Integer zona = jsonObject.getInt("zona");
                        Integer distrito = jsonObject.getInt("distrito");
                        Integer ubicacion = jsonObject.optInt("ubicacion", 0);
                        Boolean eliminado = jsonObject.getBoolean("eliminado");
                        Predio predio = predioSQL.getPredio(id_remota);
                        if (predio != null) {
                            predio.setNombre(nombre);
                            predio.setCodigo_siscop(codigo_siscop);
                            predio.setCodigo_sap(codigo_sap);
                            predio.setZona(zona);
                            predio.setDistrito(distrito);
                            predio.setUbicacion(ubicacion);
                            predio.setEliminado(eliminado);
                            predioSQL.updatePredio(predio);
                        } else {
                            predio = new Predio(null, id_remota, nombre, codigo_siscop, codigo_sap, zona, distrito, ubicacion, eliminado);
                            predioSQL.addPredio(predio);
                        }

                        porcAvance = (int) Math.round(i * division);
                        publishProgress(porcAvance);
                    }
                    if (next.equals("null")) {
                        sincronizacionSQL.setFechaSincronizacionModulo("predios", fecha);
                    } else {
                        sincronizar(next, null);
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return true;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
            int progreso = values[0];
            pDialog.setProgress(progreso);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
            if(result)
            {
                pDialog.dismiss();
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onCancelled() {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Tarea cancelada!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

}
```

Quedo atento a sus comentarios, saludos.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
System.err: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
```

Te sugiero realices la prueba usando únicamente `Volley` sin tener que crear un `Asynctask`. `Volley` en realidad administra las conexiones en threads independientes, algo similar a un `Asynctask`.

Utilizas `Volley` o `Asynctask` pero no los dos al mismo tiempo:
[**Android Volley vs Asynctask** (en inglés)](http://www.truiton.com/2015/02/android-volley-vs-asynctask-better-approach/)

Comment: Tienes razón estoy ejecutando `sincronizar(next, null);` dentro del  `doInBackground`, lo agregué dentro del `onPostExecute` y funciona de maravilla.

Comment: Perfecto, dentro de onPostExecute() ya no se ejecuta en el thread.

Comment: @Marcelo es posible que usted este llamando a progressDialog, y este solo puede ser visible desde el Thread de la interface de usuario, o mejor dicho desde thread con Looper, HandlerThread -> http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/os/HandlerThread.html Saludos